# What is the optimal way to search a large ordered sequence

Tags: scala

Say I have an extremely large sequence (more than a million entries) of values that are in chronological order:

```
case class A(ts: Long, value: Double)

val sequence: Seq[A] = // Filled in chronological order
```

And I want to search for the latest item in the sequence that occurs before a given time. So something like the following:

```
def lastBefore(time: Long) = sequence.indexWhere(_.ts >= time) match {
    case i if i > 0 => Some(sequence(i))
    case _ => None
}
```

I am wondering what is the fastest way to implement lastBefore(). I was thinking I could use a binarySearch approach but am wondering would there be an advantage in using something like a SortedMap or TreeMap implementation?

Comment: First, your current implementation makes two traversal/access of the sequence where it could do only one. Depending on the underlying type, this could make a significant difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binary search is probably the best solution to efficiently find an item in a sorted collection while minimizing complexity. However, using a `Seq` is not necessarily the best choice, because a `Seq` does not give you any guarantee with regards to having the possibility of efficiently accessing items in the collection by its index (in fact, the default backing implementation of a `Seq` is a `List`, whose `apply` method is linear in complexity).

You can however use binary search on an `IndexedSeq` (like `Vector`s and `Array`s) and you don't even have to implement it yourself, since binary search is the method used by default by the `search` method for `IndexedSeq`s. As [the documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/IndexedSeq.html#search%5BB%3E:A%5D(elem:B)(implicitord:scala.math.Ordering%5BB%5D):collection.Searching.SearchResult) says:

> Search this sorted sequence for a specific element. If the sequence is an IndexedSeq, a binary search is used. Otherwise, a linear search is used.

Something like the following should suit your needs:

```
import scala.collection.Searching.Found
import scala.collection.Searching.InsertionPoint

final case class A(ts: Long, value: Double)

val sequence: IndexedSeq[A] = Vector(A(1,1), A(2,2), A(3,3), A(5,5))

def lastBefore(time: Long): Option[A] =
  sequence.search(A(time, 0))(math.Ordering.by(_.ts)) match {
    case Found(0) | InsertionPoint(0) => None
    case Found(foundIndex) => Some(sequence(foundIndex - 1))
    case InsertionPoint(insertionPoint) => Some(sequence(insertionPoint - 1))
  }

assert(lastBefore(1) == None)
assert(lastBefore(2) == Some(A(1,1)))
assert(lastBefore(4) == Some(A(3,3)))
assert(lastBefore(10) == Some(A(5,5)))
```

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/YE062gTHSVmBMgarAmyZkQ/15).

Notice that I got away with using `search` here using a dummy value as part of the search class you are using since it doesn't seem like it's considered for the search.